# Please suggest a better property name for Items Order Index (in a list)

Tags: naming, naming-conventions

Hi I have a class of let's say "Channels", like folders - but it could be menu items in a navigation block. So obviously a "Channel" has properties like

```
.Title
.Alias (wordPress slug-like)
.Content
.RedirectUrl (may act as a hyperlink)

.StateProperties.IsActive
.StateProperties.IsFeatured
```

/// etc..

but **in many cases I would want to set the order of my items in a navigation menu block manually** - by whatever importance I decide, right.. ? (not by abc or timestamp)

**So I've added a property called
`StateProperties.OrderIndex`** just for this... a colleague of mine has called it "z-index" while he was referring to it... I am trying to build a CMS framework for our internal needs and just seeking your opinions as to what name could possibly be used for my "OrderIndex" ?
To me "OrderIndex" just makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe 'OrderIndex' is exactly what you are looking for, since index stands for position and you are setting an 'Order' position. The 'Z' in 'z-index' stands for depth position, which does not seem to match what you are trying to go for.

Comment: Allrighty sounds good :) I would mark that as the answer (coz after all I don't have all day to think about it) but please do add comments if there is anything to add...

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer Order or Sequence. I think z-index carries a different meaning that what you're after (more for ordering on a stack).